# How to make popover view show up on iPhone like it does on iPad with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, popover

[image]I am building an app using SwiftUI, and wanted to create a small popover with a small paragraph and maybe a button. I have tried multiple things but can't figure out how to make it show up as a popover like on iPad instead of Modally.

Comment: do you mean action sheet or alert? can you add the picture of what you wants?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani Please read the question. It clearly states SwiftUI

Comment: If you look at the Apple Music app, they use it in songs for the sort button. That means it will come in a Switui update soon. Hopefully quickly

Comment: @Pbk that is the new SwiftUI Menu feature. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry. Misunderstood question. The following is not a correct answer:**
If you want to open a modal window, you need something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {

    @State private var show_modal_window: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.show_modal_window = true
            }) {
                Text("Show modal")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$show_modal_window) {
                ModalView()
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}

struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test()
    }
}
```

And you need to create another Swift View as a separate file. In my example it is named "ModalView"

Comment: I realized my question was confusing. I am trying to make a popover window show up on iPhone similar to the way it shows on iPad. I added a picture of what I wanted as an example.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI does not contain UIModalPresentationStyle analog for now. So you need to use some custom UIViewRepresentable to use UIKit feature to have what you asked for.